# Why For Let loop is returning numbers instead of data?

Tags: javascript

Accessing local csv file to obtain data in column A, using "for (let" is returning numbers and not the text data.

Have searched but no solutions.

```
const searchkeywords = fs.readFileSync('kwords.csv');
    for (let kword of searchkeywords) {
    console.log(`Search Keyword: ${kword}`);
    }
```

Need to retrieve actual text from csv file.

Comment: `readFileSync` returns a buffer. you need to convert it to a string first https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

Comment: It's a `for...of` loop.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 0):

By default readFileSync returns buffer. Just add second argument like 'utf8'.

```
   const searchkeywords = fs.readFileSync('kwords.csv', 'utf8');
    for (let kword of searchkeywords) {
        console.log(`Search Keyword: ${kword}`);
    }
```

Comment: Care to explain _what_ you've changed and _why_?

Comment: He just added `encoding` parameter for `readFileSync` method. So the method reads in the file `utf-8` encoded, which means there is no need to afterwards convert the buffer to string.

Comment: @Yaroslav Gaponov
Thank you, it is returning only the first character of the string.